# Auto create missing folder with perl

Tags: perl

Hi im very new to programming and perl , I badly need help.
Requirement : Currently creating an auto folder creating also with subfolder if wrongly delete.
              To call the subfolder I did not hard code, all sub folder consist of 9. So use "for" loop function and "array" to make sure all the subfolder exist once folder is deleted.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dirname = "/srv/ym/home/ymadm/transfer/ymtrans/YM/sharmila";
my $dirname1 = '/srv/ym/home/ymadm/transfer/ymtrans/YM/sharmila/';

my @folder = qw(test1 test2 abc def efg);
my $exists = ` if [ -d '$dirname' ] ; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi `;
$exists =~ s/\n$//;
    if ($exists eq '1')
    {
            print "exists";

    }
    else
    {
        unless(mkdir($dirname, 0777)) 
        {
            die "Unable to create $dirname\n";
        }

    chmod(0777, $dirname) or die "Couldn't chmod $dirname: $!";


        for(my $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i = $i + 1 ) 
        {

            unless(mkdir($dirname1.$i.@folder, 0777)) 
            {
                die "Unable to create $dirname1\n";
            }



            chmod(0777, $dirname1.$i.@folder) or die "Couldn't chmod $dirname1.$i: $!";
        }    


    }
print "\n";
```

Comment: Chorobas soltion would create the folder:
/srv/ym/home/ymadm/transfer/ymtrans/YM/sharmila/test1/test2/abc/def/efg
Is this what you want, or do you want the folder 
/srv/ym/home/ymadm/transfer/ymtrans/YM/sharmila/test1,
/srv/ym/home/ymadm/transfer/ymtrans/YM/sharmila/test2
/srv/ym/home/ymadm/transfer/ymtrans/YM/sharmila/abc,
/srv/ym/home/ymadm/transfer/ymtrans/YM/sharmila/def,
/srv/ym/home/ymadm/transfer/ymtrans/YM/sharmila/efg ?

Comment: Georg : find my ans code as below, that's what exactly I need but do comment if anything wrong with the code

Answer (score 1):

No need to shell out for `-d`, Perl has the same operator.

To create a path with all the missing parts recreated, use `make_path` from [File::Path](http://p3rl.org/File::Path):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw{ say };

use File::Path qw{ make_path };

my $dirname  = "/srv/ym/home/ymadm/transfer/ymtrans/YM/sharmila";
my @folders  = qw( test1 test2 abc def efg );

my $fullpath = join '/', $dirname, @folders;

if (-d $fullpath) {
    say 'Exists.';
} else {
    make_path($fullpath);  # mode => 0777 is the default
    say 'Created.';
}
```

Comment: klmxv100:/srv/ym/home/ymadm/app/bin>$ ./test9.pl
Feature "test1" is not supported by Perl 5.24.0 at ./test9.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test9.pl line 4.
I got this

Comment: any suggestin, the script only created one subfolder not the rest of the subfolder and without full permission

Comment: @eniasharmila: Folders created for sample `$dirname`.. You should use `foreach`, `for` or `while` to create a multiple subdirs

Comment: it works after I change if (-d $fullpath) {
to if(-e $fullpath){

Comment: Are you sure the full path is a folder, not a file?

Comment: yes I wan folder not file, the requirement is to auto create missing folder

Comment: below code I posted the answer, it works with below code with full permission in Linux, do review and let know if anything need to change